# abandoned memory problems with the heap

Tags: ios, memory, heap-memory, instruments, allocation

I am trying to learn a bit about the instruments panel in Xcode. I am using ARC. When checking allocations I have been coming up with some abandoned memory it issues. The picture below depicts code from my prepareForSegue method. Every time I tap to perform the segue, memory is allocated and never released. So if I go back and forth between the two viewControllers, the memory keeps climbing and eventually terminates the app. I used the tools to narrow down the problems in the code but am unsure where to go from here. I have seen several examples online about how to identify the problem but not about how to resolve it. So my question is, what is going on here that is causing the app to not release the memory?

[image: prepareForSegue method]

properties for viewController 1:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *recAlbumsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *titlesArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *timersArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *albumsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *imagesArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *objsIdArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *imagesDataArray;

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray *recAlbumData;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray *albumData;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *albumTitle;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *objId;
```

properties for viewController 2:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *album;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *albumRef;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *objId;
```

I have tried setting all the properties to nil in a viewDidDisappear method and also tried removing the 1st viewController from the viewController array hierarchy but nothing changed.